# MySQL Executing multiple INSERTs in 1 query

Tags: php, mysql, database

Hey guys I was wondering is it possible to use more than 1 INSERT at a time per query? Or does each INSERT have to be done one at a time?

For example I would like to execute these 2 queries as one to save on server resources:

```
INSERT INTO ExtraStats (date, supportStaff, startEmails, endEmails, emailsAnswered) VALUES ('2012-09-01', '5', '4', '3', '2') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE supportStaff = '5', startEmails = '4', endEmails = '3', emailsAnswered = '2'
INSERT INTO ExtraStats (date, supportStaff, startEmails, endEmails, emailsAnswered) VALUES ('2012-09-2', '5', '6', '7', '8') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE supportStaff = '5', startEmails = '6', endEmails = '7', emailsAnswered = '8'
```

Is there anyway of combining them? I tried just sticking them in the same query but it didn't like it.

Comment: make a stored procedure and call it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can try this

```
INSERT INTO tbl_name(col1,col2,col3) VALUES ('aaa','bbb','ccc'),('ddd','eee','fff');
```

or you can put semicolon after first query and continue with second one.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

```
INSERT INTO ExtraStats (date, supportStaff, startEmails, endEmails, emailsAnswered) 
VALUES ('2012-09-01', '5', '4', '3', '2') 
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE supportStaff = '5', startEmails = '4', endEmails = '3', emailsAnswered = '2';

('2012-09-2', '5', '6', '7', '8') 
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE supportStaff = '5', startEmails = '6', endEmails = '7', emailsAnswered = '8'
```

Answer (score 0):

seprate by semicolon ";" like :

```
INSERT INTO ExtraStats (date, supportStaff, startEmails, endEmails, emailsAnswered) 
VALUES ('2012-09-01', '5', '4', '3', '2') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE supportStaff = '5', 
startEmails = '4', endEmails = '3', emailsAnswered = '2';

INSERT INTO ExtraStats (date, supportStaff, startEmails, endEmails, emailsAnswered) VALUES 
('2012-09-2', '5', '6', '7', '8') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE supportStaff = '5', startEmails = 
'6', endEmails = '7', emailsAnswered = '8';
```